# How to write a List(of) to a text file and retrieve it (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

Title. I need to write my ListOf, which just contains values such as Zero, Zero, One, One, Two, etc to a text file, and then load back up again. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried searching for this? Stack Overlow is the last place you should turn to when looking for _help_ doing something.

Comment: Take a look at XmlSerializer - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VisualVincent I have tried searching for it, i didnt understand what i found but i do nw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello & Welcome to Stack Overflow!.
 In the future please show some effort when asking a question and at least google or even bing your question first, there are a stack of tutorials regarding your question.
With that being said, I am going to give you a lifeline.
From what I can tell, you want to write your list to a text file and then read from that text file.

```
Module Module1
Dim mylist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim desktopPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim newfile As String = "myTextFile.txt"
Dim newPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, newfile)

Sub Main()
    mylist.Add("Zero")
    mylist.Add("One")
    mylist.Add("Two")
    mylist.Add("Three")
    writer()
End Sub

Sub writer()
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(newPath)
        For Each item As String In mylist
            sw.WriteLine(item)
        Next
        sw.Flush() ''yeap I'm the sort of person that flushes it then closes it
        sw.Close()
    End Using
    reader()
End Sub

Sub reader()
    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(newPath)
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd)
        sr.Close()
    End Using
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```

I didn't put too much effort into this, I will leave the rest up to you, however this should get your well and truly on your way.
This was done with a Console application
Also if you have any problems or even a question or two regarding my answer,
 leave a comment and I will do my best to answer you and help you out as I know learning something for the first time can be difficult and you will have lots of questions.
EDIT: If you need to load each value separately eg skip the first 4 lines and only read the 5th line, you should look into learning how to do a loop. 

EDIT - Here is what I think you are trying to achieve just from reading your comments.

```
''Reads whatever is in the newPath Textfile and addes the words to a listbox or wherever is needed.
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear() ''This is stop double ups.
    Dim myTextFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(newPath)
    For Each word As String In myTextFile
        ListBox1.Items.Add(word) '' change this to mylist if need be 
        ''mylist.Add(word)
    Next
End Sub
```

This should fix your problem, although you may need to clear the `mylist` first or even create another array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i did do some research, but i didnt find anything like this. Thanks for the help. Im not using it in the console, rather in a form, and im unsure of how the headings equate, im going to try it

Comment: instead of using `writer()` using a button click event and just add the code that that is to follow for each `sub`

Comment: The writer works! My other question is my program is kind of like a probability generator. The values have been written to the txt file, and I also wanted to know how to load those values back into the list after the program is closed. Users would initially add the values with buttons, so its kinda of like a save slot i guess

Comment: @microchipj13 : The fastest way to read the values back into the list is to load the lines into an array and call `ToList()` on that. See [**File.ReadAllLines()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent could you explain what you mean, im not sure i understand fully

Comment: yeah @VisualVincent is right, it would also give you more control over what is writing to the screen eg `textbox1.text= mylist[2]` this would right the 3rd value of the array

Comment: @microchipj13 can you explain your question about closing the program and wanting to add your text file items to your array? because the way I have written it, each time you open the program it will automatically at the values `"Zero","One","Two","Three"` to your array (`mylist()`)

Comment: The way my program works is that users press buttons that add the strings Zero- Eleven to the list. So if a user wants to get the data they put in before, the text file can be loaded back into the list and then i can use my probability function. SO the buttons do what the add statements do

Comment: so you just want the user to be able to press a button that read everything for the text file and add it to a listbox?

Comment: see my edited answer to what I think you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @microchipj13 : I don't understand which part you didn't understand. I gave you the info you need to achieve your task. `File.ReadAllLines()` will generate an array, that array can be converted into a `List(Of T)` by calling `.ToList()` on it.

Comment: @Werdna : Why iterate it? `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(<path>))`.

Comment: @VisualVincent hey Vincent, I haven't seen you here for a while, good to hear from you :) I was trying to show our friend how a simple loop could fix hes/her problem. it's funny the code above that you have mentioned is the first thing i thought about writing, however I thought this would be a better learning experience for him/her.

Comment: `I haven't seen you here for a while` - About 50 min ago :). -- Jokes aside, I have been active almost everyday. Things have been a little slow on the answer front, but I comment almost every day (I hang around in the C# area too, btw). -- Glad to see you too! I have seen you around in a few posts but not as many as you used to.

Comment: I have been reading books about JavaScript as of late, So that would be why, I still visit the site everyday, I mean who wouldn't, its an awesome tool!

Comment: Agreed. If it was possible, I'd be getting the Fanatic badge once again soon (170 consecutive days, and counting!). :)

Comment: wow wee, we are pretty much the same `visited 177 days, 164 consecutive`

Comment: @Werdna your code was pretty much what i needed, thank you so much. Ive got a bit of headway to make but this is much more clear, thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure mate :) all the best, please mark the question as correct for the next person :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sandbox code:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmTest

    Dim l1 As New List(Of String)

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        l1.AddRange({"1", "b", "7"})
        Dim mySerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of String)))
        ' To write to a file, create a StreamWriter object.
        Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\temp\list.xml")
        mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, l1)
        myWriter.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\temp\list.xml", FileMode.Open)
        Dim mySerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of String)))
        ' Call the Deserialize method and cast to the object type.
        l1 = New List(Of String) ' refresh for test
        l1 = CType(mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream), List(Of String))
        Stop ' l1 is populated
    End Sub
End Class
```